# touch location not detected in scroller view

Tags: ios, swift, location, touch

I'm trying to move an image from a scroller view to other points on the screen. It works when I touch outside of the scroller view (named optionScroller) but nothing is detected inside the scroller view.:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent: UIEvent?) {
    self.movingImageView.image = nil


    }

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches ){

        location = touch.locationInView(view)

        movingImageView.center = location

    }}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in (touches ){

        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        movingImageView.center = location

}}
```

Comment: Have you tried using hitTest?

Comment: Eric Small, one quick thing to look at, you don't need to rip through the set of touches using a for loop, you just need to do something like this: - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 UITouch *touch = event.allTouches.anyObject;
 CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[self contentView]];
 if (CGRectContainsPoint(_nahd.frame, touchLocation) || CGRectContainsPoint(_certSelect.frame, touchLocation)) {
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
 } else {
  return;
 }
}
That's objective-C, this won't fix your problem but it will simply what you are doing

Comment: I think i answered my own question. I had to convert the touch location in the scroller view to the view:   locationRelativeToScreen = option1InsertImageView.convertPoint(location ,toView: view)